# nodemon app isn't working

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am fresher at nodejs and was just building a basic project. I used nodemon, at first it worked perfectly but after few minutes it showed up this error in gitbash.
**Error: **
[gitbash showing up error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzXbX.png)

I've made an app.js file, whose contents are shown below...

**app.js : **

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

//init app
const app = express();

//load view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//home route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
let articles = [
{
id:1,
title:'article one',
body:'this is article one'
}
{
id:2,
title:'article two',
body:'this is article two'
}
{
id:3,
title:'article three',
body:'this is article three'
}
];
res.render('index', {
title:'Article',
articles: articles
});
});
//Add Routes
app.get('/articles/add', function(req, res) {
res.render('add_article', {
title:'Add Article'
});
});
//start server
app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('server started on port 3000...!');
});
```

Please help me get out of this, I got stuck in this problem since one week.
Thank you in

Comment: I hope you found your answer even though one is not marked. This is rather old, and I don't think it will be helpful to anyone with the current title. I recommend this question be removed.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
let articles = [
{
  ...
},
{
  ...
},
...
```

You need to use `,` to separate each element of an Array. That's a Syntax Error and your nodemon is working well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with nodemon, Nodemon is a utility package, which watch the changes in your code and restart the server. Read more about Nodemon from [here](https://nodemon.io/)

Coming back to problem, You are making a JSON object Array named articles, you are missing comma separators after every closing of the curly braces.

It should be like this

```
let articles = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}];
```